# How to Get dynamic data attribute through jQuery event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple movie app learning jQuery, where a user can look up titles of movies and then get more information on a specific title after an initial search. I need to grab the data attribute 'movieId' to make the second search. Here is my code...

```
                <tr class="row">
                    <td data-movieId="${movieId}">
                        <p class="movie-title"><a href="#">${movie.title}</a></p>
                        <p class="release-date">${releaseDate}</p>
                        <p>${movie.overview}</p>
                    </td> 
                    <td><img class="poster-image movie-poster" src="${posterBaseUrl + 
                        movie.poster_path}" alt=""></td>
                </tr>



                function clickOnMovieTitle() {
                   $('.content').on('click', function(event) {
                     event.preventDefault();
                     let clickedMovie = $(event.currentTarget).closest('td').data('movieId')
                     movieApiReq(clickedMovie);
                    })
                 }
```

clickedMovie is returning undefined. I have also tried using .attr() and had the same result. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There's no `.content` in the posted code

Comment: Are you even using the template literals correctly? The value of your `movieId` without the backticks would simply be `"${movieId}"`, not a computed one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="row">
        <td data-movieId="${movieId}">
          <p class="movie-title"><a href="#">${movie.title}</a></p>
          <p class="release-date">${releaseDate}</p>
          <p>${movie.overview}</p>
        </td>
        <td><img class="poster-image movie-poster" src="${posterBaseUrl + 
                        movie.poster_path}" alt=""></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You can do it like this:

```
$('.row').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let td = $(event.target).closest('td')[0];
    let movieId = $(td).data('movieid');
    console.log(movieId);
  })
```

Notice the **lower case** of `'movieid'`.

Comment: This is almost the same as in the question. Difficult to make any assumptions and provide solutions without more info from OP

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it. I was also unaware that the data attribute is obtained through all lower case.